# Draw and Quantity

Tags: graphics, units

I'd like to use Quantity in my graphics, but I can't figure out how to do it even for a very simple Circle.

```
(* draw a circle with center in (3,2) and radius 5 *)

Graphics[Circle[{3, 2}, 5]]

(* why it won't work with Quantity? *)

x = Quantity[3, "Meters"];
y = Quantity[2, "Meters"];
r = Quantity[5, "Meters"];

Graphics[Circle[{x, y}, r]]
```

Errors are:

1) Coordinate {Quantity[3, "Meters"], Quantity[2, "Meters"]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

2) Radius Quantity[5, "Meters"] should be a positive number or pair of positive numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Could you help me please?
Thank you, Luca-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantity itself can't be used as its own value. You need to extract the numerical value itself, like this

```
x = Quantity[3, "Meters"];
y = Quantity[2, "Meters"];
r = Quantity[5, "Meters"];

Graphics[Circle[{QuantityMagnitude[x, "Meters"], 
           QuantityMagnitude[y, "Meters"]}, 
           QuantityMagnitude[r, "Meters"]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can think of `Quantity` as an "object" with one of its properties is its numerical value (with no units) that you can obtain from the object with the `QuantityMagnitude` call

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry I haven't enough reputation points to vote up your answer.
Is Magnitude a property of Quantity objects? Is there a way to inspect properties of a give object? For instance, if I have a Point[] object, is there a way to inspect what properties I can query? Thank you again, Luca-

Comment: @Luca  M is not OO Language, but uses functions. So to find what "methods" can be used on "object" `Point` you look at help and see all the settings and commands that can be applied to it. Also if you do `??Point` you'll see the options `Options[Point]={VertexColors->None,VertexNormals->None}` There are also modifiers you can apply to point, such as `PointSize` and change its color etc...

Comment: ok, thank you. My path to learn Mathematica seems "not so short"!

Comment: I think it would be better to extract numbers for an explicit unit, otherwise mixed units will give unexpected results. In v10 that would be something like `QuantityMagnitude[x,"Meters"]`, for v9 you'd need an extra call to `UnitConvert`...

Comment: @AlbertRetey  good point. Since the units are all the same in this example, this will not make a difference, but will update for illustration and to remind one of this. thanks.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make a difference in this example, but if one uses the same units everywhere, then the use of quantities only adds overhead :-)

Answer (score 5):

Another explanation is, that `Circle` is a graphical primitive, not a pure mathematical function in itself, and therefore does not accept units.

When one uses a mathematical object, units *can* be used throughout.

**Example:** The circle centered on $(xc,yc)$ with radius $r$
$$(x-xc)^2+(y-yc)^2=r^2$$
can be drawn *with units* in *Mathematica* using `ContourPlot`:

```
{xc,yc,r}=Quantity[#, "Meters"]&/@{3,2,5};

ContourPlot[(x-xc)^2 + (y-yc)^2 == r^2,
  {x, Quantity[-3, "Meters"], Quantity[8, "Meters"]},
  {y, Quantity[-3, "Meters"], Quantity[8, "Meters"]}, 
  PlotRange->{{-10,10}, {-10,10}}]
```

[image: output]

*Mathematica* automatically takes care of converting units, so you can mix e.g. "Feet" and "Millimeters" etc.

Comment: thank you for your further explanation! Does the same problem (a graphics primitive that doesn't accept units) apply also to Arrows[], Point[] and so on?

Comment: @Luca: Yes, I think so. Just give it a try.

Comment: Honestly I don't think that it is worth to spend too much effort to understand/explain something like this. It simply reflects what WRI's programmers did implement, I think it would be possible to have graphics primitives accept quantities as well. If they don't but `ContourPlot` does then this IMHO looks somewhat inconsistent, but probably for good reasons (e.g. performance, consistency, compatibility...) and most probably has to just be accepted "as is"...